# Декоратор на питоне

Tags: python, функции, декоратор, аргументы

Надо сделать декоратор который будет вызывать функцию указанное количество раз, написал это:

```
def n_times(n):
    def b(f):
        def c(*args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(n):
                f(*args, **kwargs)
        return c
    return b
```

Для функций без аргументов и функций с аргументами которые я могу придумать все работает. Для некоторой неизвестной мне функции возвращает это:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__wrapped__'
```

Что это? И как исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте подключить `from functools import wraps` и к функции `def c` добавить декоратор `@wraps(f)`

Comment: @andreymal сработало)

Comment: А зачем тут wraps/__wrapped__?

Comment: @andreymal поддержу последний комент - можно подробностей, что это и как влияет на декораторы?

Comment: @cauf а я сам не знаю, видимо у автора какая-то проверялка кода ожидает использование wraps и лезет в его внутренности

Comment: @cauf это специальная тестирующая система. чтоб домашки по питону в нее сдавать